# Drop random activity once it has been shown

Tags: android

Once a random activity is done how can it not show up again upon button click? See my random code below. I just can't figure it out.Thanks

```
 public void onClick(View view){
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int x=rnd.nextInt(4)+1;
        Intent intent = new Intent();


        switch (x){
            case 1:
                intent.setClass(this,John.class);
                break;

            case 2:
                intent.setClass(this,Caleb.class);
                break;

            case 3:
                intent.setClass(this,Isaiah.class);
                break;

            case 4:
                intent.setClass(this,Jacob.class);
                break;
        }
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Call `finish()` below `startActivity(intent)`.

This will end the current activity after the call for the new one.

Comment: Hey McGuile, The finish() doesn't  seems to work. The activity that I add this method to still comes up in the random code.I'm looking to have that activity to no longer show up after it has been viewed. So if there are 5 activities, after activity #1 is viewed then only the remaining 4 are now viewable. I'm still learning so any help is appreciated. Thx.

Comment: public void onClick(View view){
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int x=rnd.nextInt(4)+1;
    Intent intent = new Intent( );


    switch (x){
        case 1:
            intent.setClass(this,John.class);
            break;
        case 2:
            intent.setClass(this,Caleb.class);
            break;
        case 3:
            intent.setClass(this,Isaiah.class);
            break;
        case 4:
            intent.setClass(this,Jacob.class);
            break;
    }

    startActivity(intent);
    finish();

Comment: Hi, can you try this.finish() or getActivity.finish()?

Comment: Hey, I tried both but it still didn't work. Not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

Maintain a List of the positions that you have started. Once you start an activity, put that position into the list. Once you generate the random number, look up the list and if it contains that number, repeat to generate the random number. Repeat this until two values are remaining and choose one of the two !